# Delphi outlook getting error message as "invalid class string"

Tags: delphi

```
program MailWithOutlook;    
procedure SendOutlookMail;
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  vMailItem: variant;
begin
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application'); // error occurs on here as "Invalid Class string"
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;
  vMailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
  vMailItem.Recipients.Add('nitinshevale555@gmail.com');
  vMailItem.Subject := 'test email';
  vMailItem.Body := 'This is a test';
  vMailItem.Attachments.Add('C:\temp\sample.txt');
  vMailItem.Send;    
  VarClear(Outlook);
end;
end.
```

Please suggest any solution for sending email through outlook using Delphi 7.
Outlook is also open. I think it is the version error throgh the registry file. but not getting the actual result.

Comment: In Delphi 5 there were Office components including `TOutlookApplication` component. So there is one in Delphi 7 too. Drop it onto your form and work wit hit.

Comment: The suggestion from that error is that `Outlook.Application` is not a registered ProgID on your machine, or the registry data for its registration has become corrupted somehow. `GetActiveOleObject` translates that ProgID to a ClassID using a Windows COM API called `CLSIDFromProgID` and, as you'll see in the documentation here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - one of the possible return values corresponds to your error: `CO_E_CLASSSTRING`

Comment: The suggestion in this MS support document - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2827747 - is to repair your Office installation, assuming Office (specifically Outlook) is indeed installed

Comment: The real problem is that you've copied this code without great understanding. The error message is very clear, once you understand COM. So make that your next topic of learning. Make sure you know what a class string is.

Comment: Thanks Blong.. The suggestion in this MS support document - support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2827747 - is to repair your Office installation, assuming Office (specifically Outlook) is indeed installed – blong  .- In Registry Outlook.Application entry is missing. I will try that.   David Heffernan - this code also working on  5 out of 3 computers. I think that error was Registry file.

Comment: Well, the COM class registry is indeed held in the registry, so that's hardly surprising. This is my point though. I think it would benefit you to learn enough to understand the error message.